# Haskell: Parse error in case statement (involving lists!)

Tags: list, parsing, haskell, compiler-errors, tree

I'm having trouble with (I assume) the types I am working with (for an assignment on huffman coding) in my case statement. I want to work from the top of the tree down to each leaf and return a list of key value pairs. [ ] passes fine, but [h] returns a parse error and I'm not sure why.

```
type HCode = [Bit]
data Bit = L | R deriving (Eq, Show)
data Tree a = Leaf Int a | Node Int (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Eq)

convert :: Ord a => HCode -> Tree a -> [(a,HCode)]
convert hs tree =
  case hs tree of
    []     (Node _ a b) -> (convert [L]            a)++(convert [R]            b)
    [h]    (Node _ a b) -> (convert !([h]++[L])    a)++(convert !([h]++[R])    b)
    (h:hs) (Node _ a b) -> (convert !((h:hs)++[L]) a)++(convert !((h:hs)++[R]) b)
    [h]    (Leaf _ a)   -> [(a, [h])]
    (h:hs) (Leaf _ a)   -> [(a, (h:hs))]
```

Also I haven't used bangs before but I think they are appropriate here? Would they have an impact on performance? Am I even using them in the right context?

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate question about bang patterns.  One question - per stackoverflow question is best.  In short: No, you aren't using them right.

Comment: The bangs don't make much sense to me here, but I could be wrong. Either way I think that's a separate question than the pattern-matching problem you're having.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson yeah was only a minor side question, a yes or no was all I was looking for, so thanks

Answer (score 3):

`case a b of ...` does not match against both `a` and `b`, but rather matches on the result of calling `a` as a function, with the argument `b`. A `case` expression always matches against exactly one value, and even the first clause (which you think is working) is definitely not working.

To match against two values, you wrap them up in a tuple, and then break apart the tuple in each clause, like so:

```
case (hs, tree) of
  ([], (Node _ a b)) -> ...
  ([h], (Node _ a b)) -> ...
  ...
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense. In that case, why does the compiler not give me a parse error for the first line?

Comment: @420fedoras I think it's a phase thing.  By playing a little in ghci, it seems like `[] x` *does* parse as a pattern (same was a `Just x`), since `[]` is considered to be a constructor.  Then later, during typechecking, it complains that `[]` was given too many arguments.